# How to designate server location?

Tags: firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to designate Firebase server location (eg to Europe/US)? If so how?

I noticed that this was possible for Google Cloud Platform, but couldn't find the equivalent for Firebase.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Firebase Database instances are currently located in the central US.

There is no way to have your data stored in a different location.

Comment: Doesn't affects the latency of the app? what is Google Cloud Region?  Google Cloud Region in India available means any benefits for firebase available?

Comment: Is this still the case, 1.3 years later?

Comment: i guess [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) can help you guys